# change location with a more elegant way

Tags: javascript, arrays, location

I need to reload the page on a select box change. My solution works well, but I'm sure there is more elegant way to do so.

The main issue is that the url varies.

http://domain.tld/homepage/**germany**/privacy

The part of the domain `germany` can change. On select box change event, the current value of the select box should be attached to the domain with a slash, so that the url looks likes this i.e.

http://domain.tld/homepage/germany/privacy**/4**

Actually I cannot only attach in the onchange event the current selected value, because then, I would get these results on several change events:

http://domain.tld/homepage/germany/privacy**/4/60/6**

So is there a more elegant way, to do the same my function does?

```js
    function reloadPrivacyPage(language) {
            var locationUrl = window.location.pathname;
            var locationUrlSplitted = locationUrl.split('/');
            locationUrl = '';
            for (var key in locationUrlSplitted) {
                if(locationUrlSplitted[key].length > 0) {
                    locationUrl = locationUrl + '/' + locationUrlSplitted[key];
                }
                if(locationUrlSplitted[key] === 'privacy')
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            top.location.href='http://' + window.location.host + locationUrl + '/' + language;
        }
```

```html
<form action="index.php?action=change" method="post">
            <select id="privavyLanguage" name="privacyLanguage" onchange="reloadPrivacyPage(this.value);">
                <option value="0">- Select language -</option>
                <option value="4">Deutsch</option>
                <option value="6">English</option>
                <option value="60">Polski</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: so does the /{location}/ come from the drop down and the value come from the option value? are they the only varibles that could change?

Comment: The `location` is given by a totally different thing. I just wanted to say with the location, that I cannot set a fixed value.

Comment: Where do you get the location value